# Use of GROUP_CONCAT on Mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

As far as I understand, using `or` should be avoided as much as possible as rule of thumb in query.

I have two tables having one-to-many relationship.

And I have joined two tables like below.

```
SELECT A.*, group_concat(B.info separator ','), group_concat(B.info2 separator ',')
FROM A
JOIN B
ON A.id = B.a_id
GROUP BY A.id;
```

Does using `GROUP_CONCAT` affect the performance like `or` does in MySQL? If it does, what would be the efficient way to join those tables?

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY` of `A`?  But surely not of `B`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the GROUP_CONCAT is an additional work for the MySQL involving strings, so you should expect some slow down, but rest assured it will not kill the performance of the MySQL.

To join those tables, you can use those JOINS commands that the MySQL had.
Like INNER JOIN, FULL JOIN, etc. Take a look at this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Comment: Welcome to the site, we are glad to have you! This answer does not address the OP's question though, could you expand on it to make it specific to what is being asked?

Comment: Does it make sense now?

Comment: so if I were to put indexes, which fields should be indexed? Is it wise to index `info` and `info2` fields?

Comment: @smchae - `Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables; the indexing question would be answered wrongly if, for example, `info2` were `TEXT`.

Answer (score 5):

Your interests are generally not well-served by learning somewhat vague "rules" like "`OR` should be avoided" or "`group_concat` is slow."

Neither is actually correct, they only have *elements of truth* underlying them.

Use the correct capability to accomplish your purpose, while understanding that sometimes your interests are served by modifying your purpose to accommodate inherent limitations.

Using `GROUP BY` (not simply `GROUP_CONCAT`) can cause a performance hit if the optimizer has no effective way to accommodate the grouping... but this has nothing to do with whether `GROUP BY` should be used.  If you need it, then of course you should use it... but manipulating strings is a cake-walk compared to scanning disks and sorting without an index, and the CPU cycles consumed by the concatenation are near the noise floor.

The take-away here is to understand how the optimizer sees your query, and how it plans to resolve it.  Using `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to verify that the server has made sensible choices (and that you have written a sensible query) should be second-nature to you if you want good performance.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html#explain-execution-plan

Interpreting the output can seem like a bit of a dark art, but you'll find it's worth the effort.

Comment: where is the element of truth for the `OR` being slow?

Comment: @EvanCarroll the element (nugget, grain, hint) of truth is that something like `where foo = 6 or bar = 9 or buzz = 'fizz'` may be difficult or less likely to for the optimizer to plan well, since `OR` doesn't short-circuit to false on any false value the way `AND` does... thus a candidate for an unanticipated full table scan.  When there are usable indexes for each column, the index merge optimizations help with this, but the optimizer doesn't always select them.